# HTTP Status Code when Session Times out

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session, httprequest, request-timed-out

I have an MVC 4 Application. When I make an ajax request and the server times out, it throws an exception on client:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

So my question is

a) Why it doesn't throw a 401?

b) Will it be appropriate if I check the status code of 500 to check if session timed out? Will it be a valid condition?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can check this article in msdn about the status codes:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287675(v=vs.71).aspx

a) It doesn't return unauthorized(401) status code, because its internal server error - the server does not respond, it didn't fail on authorization

HTTP Error 500 Internal server error - means something went wrong on the server so its the correct response, you can see the following article for that : http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html

b) You can write an appropriate handling of authorization failure/session timeout using action filter or global handlers, there is no need to check for status code 500 and it will be wrong to wrap up this case like that. For the session expired handling you can check this article :
http://forums.asp.net/t/1523066.aspx?Redirect+to+Login+after+Session+is+Expired+in+MVC

Comment: What if, I want to prompt the user about session expiry using client side. I mean is it possible to do session time out handling in jquery?